# get path of image file that is outside the project in java

Tags: java, image, user-interface, resources, icons

I use this code to display image that locates outside the my java project, but I got NullPointerException every time and I can only use images that are inside my project directory. why ?

```
Icon welcomeImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("D:/img/welcome.png"));
or 
Icon welcomeImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("D://img/welcome.png"));

JLabel welcomingLb = new JLabel(welcomeImg);
```

Comment: `welcome.png` sounds like an application resource, possibly a splash-screen.  Is it either?  If so, the advice to use `File` objects is not the way to go.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8462092/418556) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) class to access your file since you are giving its full path.

Try instead :

```
Icon welcomeImg = new ImageIcon("D:/img/welcome.png");
```

Source : Javadoc of [ImageIcon(String filename)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

[`getResource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) expects the resource to be on the classpath.

If you want to read from a random file, use a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), or use the [`ImageIcon` constructor that takes a file name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

See: [Loading resources using getClass().getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource)

Basically when you use getResource it is expecting the file to be on the Classpath.  There is also a constructor for ImageIcon that takes a String filename, so you can pass the path to the Icon file directly.

Check out the [JavaDoc for ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.lang.String))

Comment: I am stuck with Java 1.2 at work because we are using an old JVM on Windows Mobile, so 1.4 is actually a step up for me ;)

Comment: *"First result on Google"* Not if you [add a '7'](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875) (usually).

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a File, like so:

```
File f = new File("C:\\folder\\stuff\\MyFile.class");
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Been a while. Edited to reflect.

Comment: Well, that's worse, because those are backslashes and need to be escaped.